# Pass parameter in the select of a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am building a query but I need to pass the parameters that I am sending to the model to be used in the query, the problem is that I can not make the query accept the parameters within the select, this is my query:

```
  def self.reporte_inventario_total(params)
    query = select("(SELECT Ruta FROM Rutas WHERE IdRutas = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AS Ruta,
      ISNULL((SELECT S.Stock/PP.PzaXCja AS INT FROM stockhistorico S LEFT JOIN ProductosXPzas PP ON S.Articulo=PP.Producto WHERE S.Articulo=Productos.Clave AND S.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '' AND fecha = :fechaDiaO or :fechaDiaO = ''),0) AS  StockCajas,
      ISNULL((SELECT S.Stock%PP.PzaXCja AS INT FROM stockhistorico S LEFT JOIN ProductosXPzas PP ON S.Articulo=PP.Producto WHERE S.Articulo=Productos.Clave AND S.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '' AND fecha = :fechaDiaO or :fechaDiaO = ''),0) AS StockPiezas,
      Productos.Clave, Productos.Producto, Productos.CodBarras,Productos.Sector", ({rutaId: params[:search],fechaDiaO: params[:fechaDiaO]}))

  end
```

and this is the error that I get

```
unsupported: Hash
```

Comment: You have `{`, `}` in your statement, that is what cause rails think that you have a `Hash`. Another thing is that you dont have the `?` (for replacing the data).

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla, thanks for answer, That's right, the sign "?" I am replacing it with that variable that is inside the brackets. For example in other queries in ".where" it works for me that way

Comment: @luis31, select("sqlstatement....", rutaId: params[:search], fechaDia0: params[:fechaDia0])  I think that will work. And you can also refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the `select` method unlike the `where` method expects a plain string as its argument, it doesn't allow `?` and `:variable` placeholders.

To use expressions like `:rutaId` you need to wrap the select query with a call to [`sanitize_sql_array`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array).

Assuming that `reporte_inventario_total` is a method on some `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass:

```
query_string = "SELECT Ruta FROM Rutas WHERE IdRutas = :rutaId or :rutaId ..."
query = select(sanitize_sql_array([query_string, rutaId: params[:search], fechaDiaO: params[:fechaDiaO]))
```

If `reporte_inventario_total` is a written outside of some `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass then you need to replace `sanitize_sql_array(...)` with something like `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ...)`, because that method is private and is intended to be used in models only.

Comment: My friend Thank you very much for solving my doubt, it worked fine, excelent.